# Why is $\operatorname{Hom}^R_{\mathcal{C}}(X, Y )$ the fiber of $\mathcal{C}_{\backslash Y} \to \mathcal{C}$ (Lurie's HTT)

Tags: higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

Reading Jacob Lurie's [Higher Topos Theory](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/highertopoi.pdf) I not understand the proof of the "only if" part in Proposition 1.2.12.4. It states

**Proposition 1.2.12.4.** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $\infty$-category containing an
object $Y$. The object $Y$ is strongly final if and only if, for every object
$X \in \mathcal{C}$, the Kan complex $\operatorname{Hom}^R_{\mathcal{C}}(X, Y )$ is contractible.

*Proof.* The "only if" direction is clear: the space  $\operatorname{Hom}^R_{\mathcal{C}}(X, Y )$
is the fiber of the projection $p : \mathcal{C}_{\backslash Y} \to \mathcal{C}$ over the vertex $X$.
If $p$ is a trivial fibration, then the fiber is a contractible Kan complex.

Question: Why is $\operatorname{Hom}^R_{\mathcal{C}}(X, Y )$ is precisely the
fiber of $X$ under $p$ as $\infty$-category? The construction of
$\operatorname{Hom}^R_{\mathcal{C}}(X, Y )$ (which is a Kan-complex) is **discussed on page 27**.

I think this should follow immediately from the construction of fiber product $X \times_{\mathcal{C}} \mathcal{C}_{\backslash Y}$ where we consider $X$ here as simplicial set $\cong \Delta^0$.

Nevertheless I nowhere found an construction the fiber product $A \times_C B$ of simplicial sets $A, B, C$. Moreover it might be possible that there are some different constuctions because Lurie want that if $A, B, C$ are Kan complexes, $A \times_C B$ becomes Kan complex too.

Which construction of $A \times_C B$ Lurie uses here (I found unly a construction for [direct products](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/product+of+simplices#ProductsOfSimplicialSets)), where can it be looked up explained in detail (what are $n$-simplices $(A \times_C B)_n$, face and degeneracy maps etc.) and why in case above the fiber $X \times_{\mathcal{C}} \mathcal{C}_{\backslash Y}= p^{-1}(X)$ coincides with $\operatorname{Hom}^R_{\mathcal{C}}(X, Y )$?

Comment: Lurie is using here the ordinary 1-categorical fiber product (or pullback, as some prefer to say) of simplicial sets.

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell: I feel like this is supposed to be obvious but could you give a reference where this consctruction of this *fiber product* of simplicial sets in context of HHT is explicitely described? I found only the *direct product* case https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/product+of+simplices#ProductsOfSimplicialSets, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The fiber product $A\times_CB$ depends on maps $f:A\to C$, $g:B\to C$, and is given by $\{(a,b)\in A\times B\mid f(a)=g(b)\}$

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე:
that's set theoretical definition. But we want $A\times_CB$ to be a simplicial set / Kan complex. Note that depending on category / quasi-category the fiber product in this category is NOT the naive set theoretic fiber product you wrote above.

Comment: it is literally the fiber product in the (ordinary) category of simplicial sets. This is computed, as folks were saying above, by $(A\times_C B)_n = A_n \times_{C_n}B_n$, i.e. the set of pairs of $n$-simplices which map to the same $n$-simplex in $C_n$. This is not derived, quasi-categorical, etc. In the case at hand, because $p$ is a categorical fibration, this *literal* fiber is weakly equivalent to the quasi-categorical fiber.